# How to compile dynamic html containing angular expressions

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-template

I am loading HTML containing angular expression from database.
ex db html:  `<div>{{dynamicContent}} </div>`

I already have ngModel for "dynamicContent" in my component. 
Problem: When I load html from db it prints as plain html.
 It should evaluate html and print ngModel value.

In angular 1 I was using $compile for same, how can I achive this with angular 6?

this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12 offset-md-1"  innerHtml="{{dynamicContent}}">
```

Comment: Please consider using `DomSanitizer#sanitize` which _unwraps the safe value and use it directly_ instead of `DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustHtml` which _bypasses the security and trust the given value to be safe HTML_ (note that this may expose your app to XSS security risks). See https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#sanitize and https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusthtml for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much the same thing in Angular 2+.

The right syntax is `<div [innerHTML]="theHtmlString"></div>`

The sanitization will be done automatically, preventing evil script tags from being injected into your div. Source: [Angular - Template syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation)

Comment: It prints html, but interpolation not working. angular expression are not evaluated it gets printed as plain text.

Comment: Yes as I wrote here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/45094468#45094468 you won't be able to interpolate variables in dynamic HTML, only in static HTML

Comment: Is there any another way to do this stuff.

Comment: If you have no other choice than loading HTML from your DB (which is pretty unusual), then I suggest you to replace the variables manually before rendering, or to store the HTML code as a tree of elements in your DB, then recreate them using https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2 and a recursive function

Comment: he specifically asked for something similar with $compile from AngularJs. He needs interpolation. This is just a useless answer.

Answer (score -1):

Please use the below method i think this will work for you.

`<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12 offset-md-1"  [innerHtml]="dynamicContent">`

Comment: Wrong case and useless parenthesis

Comment: @YoukouleleY yes your right if want two way binding then it is useful

Comment: Parenthesis mean "wait for an event emitted by `innerHTMLChange` and assign the emitted value into `dynamicContent`" which makes no sense since there is no such event emitter. So parenthesis are 100% useless

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186862/discussion-between-ankur-shah-and-youkouleley).

Answer (score -1):

You could do

```
div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12 offset-md-1" >{{dynamicContent | safeHtml"}}</Div>
```

or

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12 offset-md-1"  [innerHtml]="dynamicContent| safeHtml"></div>
```

Comment: It prints html, but interpolation not working. angular expression are not evaluated it gets printed as plain text.